# Adding and subtracting frequency of data

Tags: r, frequency, cumsum

Hello people of stackoverflow!
Sorry for not being able to write the data.frame as i don't know how this is done.
Please look at the image to understand what I am trying to ask~

[image: Input data]

This is my input data. I am currently trying to get the ridership of each bus looking at boarding and alighting time.

the boardstation is in order based on boardtime. we can see the bus moving to each station.

*One problem is that some people don't get on the bus on some station which isn't recorded but will get off.

[image: outdata]

if you look at the output data picture you can see that i have counted the frequency based on boarding stations per bus(numm).

Now what i am asking is that I want to count boarding and alighting and find the number of passengers are on the bus on each station. I will make an example of the product i am looking for in excel

[image: Final Output]
Looking at the final output picture you can see how many people are on the bus on each station.

Problem that could arise is that some stations people don't get on which that in input data it won't be recorded. Meaning when counting the alight frequency the station will in order of the boarding station, but the alight station will be in the frequency making it impossible to count the ridership.

If anyone could help me figure this out it would be really great.. With my super weak programming skills it has been hard to figure out how to do this. If you cant understand somethings please ask me here and i will answer back right away

Thank you

Comment: sorry for not adding. i have been doing the programming on R